# Redirection rule issue

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am looking for an htacess rules

My aim is to create redirection rule

```
  externalAAA?para1=1&para2=2
```

is redirected to

```
  /abc/bcde/aa.php?para1=1&para2=2
```

I tried rule buts is not working (i.e its redirecting but parameters are not getting passed)

```
  externalAAA?(.*) /abc/bcde/aa.php?$1
```

Comment: The code of the directives in your question are not complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags `R and QSA` for this like,

```
/externalAAA?(.*) /abc/bcde/aa.php?$1 [R,QSA]
```

**Also** write the above line before writing and other `rule` in your `htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

That should solve it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^externalAAA?para1=1&para2=2$ /abc/bcde/aa.php?para1=1&para2=2 [L]
```

Comment: Did it fix your problem?